# Best way of assigning a multidimensional list to unique values

Tags: python, list

What is the best way to assign a list of of names and values to a list of unique names? Or is there a way of ignoring the list of unique values from the start?

For example:

```
list01 = ['John Doe', 'Jane Doe']
list02 = [['John Doe', 'John Doe', 'Jane Doe', 'John Doe', 'Jane Doe'], [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]]
```

The final result should look like this:

```
list03 = [['John Doe', 'Jane Doe'], [70, 80]]
```

Thank you for your help and a great sunday to everyone!

Comment: Your question is unclear, can you please elaborate. From where does [70, 80] comes in your expected output.

Comment: `[70,80]` where do they come from?

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to do it?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question. I'm looping through both lists and sum up the values that are assigned to the names in 'list02'.

Comment: The sum of values assigned to names in list02 is 150 and not [70, 80]. Why do you expect [70, 80] in your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you want to sum the values per name, you can try something like this:

```
list01 = ['John Doe', 'Jane Doe']
list02 = [['John Doe', 'John Doe', 'Jane Doe', 'John Doe', 'Jane Doe'], [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]]

totals = {name: 0 for name in list01}
for i in range(len(list02[0])):
    totals[list02[0][i]] += list02[1][i]

list03 = [list(totals.keys()), list(totals.values())]
```

Or alternative you can try using python's list comprehension, maybe something like this:

```
list01 = ['John Doe', 'Jane Doe']
list02 = [['John Doe', 'John Doe', 'Jane Doe', 'John Doe', 'Jane Doe'], [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]]

list03 = [list01[:], [sum([x[1] for x in zip(list02[0], list02[1]) if x[0]==y]) for y in list01]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly what I was looking for!